# Message headers in Kafka (.NET)

Tags: .net, .net-core, apache-kafka, confluent-platform

If I understand correctly, the current version of confluent-kafka-dotnet (Confluent.Kafka package, version 0.11.2) does not support publishing/reading messages with [message headers](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-82+-+Add+Record+Headers). Is there a way to use message headers in .NET now? Any chances to get this functionality in the near future?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Message header support will be in the next release of `librdkafka` (see [the related GitHub pull request for `librdkafka`](https://github.com/edenhill/librdkafka/pull/1480)). With that in, it will be straightforward to add this to Confluent.Kafka. I can't guarantee when this will be done, but I can say it is relatively high priority.

For .NET specifically, see [this GitHub issue for `confluent-kafka-dotnet`](https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-dotnet/issues/393).